# Is Root Mean Squared Error computed according to model with all variables or only significant ones?

Tags: statistical-significance, rms

I made VAR model where there are some statistically insignificant variables. I ran forecast and I wanted to compute Root Mean Square Error. I tought that RMSE is computed according to model with only statistically significant variables but my software gives me results that seem to be computed from model with all variables (regardless there are also insignificant variables). Such RMSE can´t be true then. 
Thank you for any comments.

Comment: It is dependent on your software. Most of them I suppose will compute predictions with the complete model you give to it as it has no way to know what *you* consider to be significant or not.

Comment: @Nicolas, I agree. Actually, software that deliberately calculates RMSE for a different model than specified would be suspicious.

Comment: @Richard Hardy I think you mean suspect....

Comment: @NickCox, pardon my poor English! I must have meant suspect.

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 4):

First you specify the model; then you may measure its performance and do diagnostics. If you have specified a model that includes insignificant variables, that is your choice (not necessarily a bad one), and the root mean squared error (RMSE) will be calculated for this precise model. On the other hand, if you want an RMSE for a model that only includes significant variables, you need to specify that model explicitly.

Also, why do you think that *Such RMSE can´t be true then*? RMSE is a characteristic that simply exists; it does not need to be true or false. Each different model will have its RMSE, and you can compare RMSEs across models. If you calculate out-of-sample RMSEs, it actually makes sense to compare them and choose the model with the lower RMSE if your goal is model selection for forecasting under square loss.

Answer (score 1):

RMSE is a function of (predicted - actual), and the predicted value for obvious reasons will be based on all the variables you specify in the formula. The software will make no decisions about variables to drop based on significance. (Unless you are using some form of stepwise or significance based selection criteria explicitly)

Comment: Words have been omitted in the first sentence. E.g. RMSE is a particular summary (root mean square) of the differences (predicted - actual). Also "will consist of" might be better worded as "will be based on".

Comment: @NickCox: Thank you for making the point more precise. I will edit the answer to include clearer language.